# How can I move data based on string match to a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with important data in varying columns.  Here is an example of the data using `dput()`

```
structure(list(coord = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 3828L, 
5230L, 5388L, 5648L), REF = c("C", "C", "A", "T", "C", "CAA", 
"G", "C", "A"), ALT = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
"."), A = c("DP=1002", "DP=1001", "DP=1006", "DP=793", "DP=793", 
"", "DP=1010", "DP=1007", "DP=1014"), B = c("", "", "", "", "", 
"IDV=2", "", "", ""), C = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
), D = c("", "", "", "", "", "DP=793", "", "", ""), E = c("", 
"", "DP4=549,145,0,0", "", "DP4=331,151,0,0", "", "", "", ""), 
    F = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), G = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), H = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), I = c("DP4=257,729,0,1", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "DP4=444,537,0,1", "", "DP4=10,1000,0,1"), J = c("", "DP4=369,109,178,34", 
    "", "DP4=329,151,2,0", "", "DP4=331,460,0,2", "", "DP4=747,36,1,223", 
    ""), K = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), L = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ORF = c("Orf1a", "Orf1a", 
    "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a"
    ), Stop = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 3828L, 5230L, 
    5388L, 5648L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have been searching for a way to find the important data and move it to a named column so that it all is neatly arranged.  The important data is found in any column `A:L`.  The data I need to arrange neatly starts with `"DP="`, `"DP4="`, and `"IDV="`.    The output would look something like this:

```
coord   REF ALT A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   ORF Stop    Locus   AltAllele   DP  DP4 IDV
1059    C   .                                                   Orf1a   1059    T265I   T   DP=1002 DP4=257,729,0,1 
3267    C   .                                                   Orf1a   3267    T1001I  T   DP=1001 DP4=369,109,178,34  
3298    A   .                                                   Orf1a   3298    Q1011H  CorT    DP=1006 DP4=549,145,0,0 
3827    T   .                                                   Orf1a   3827    S1188L  C   DP=793  DP4=329,151,2,0 
3828    C   .                                                   Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T   DP=793  DP4=331,151,0,0 
3828    CAA .                                                   Orf1a   3828    S1188L  T   DP=793  DP4=331,460,0,2 IDV=2
5230    G   .                                                   Orf1a   5230    K1655N  CorT    DP=1010 DP4=444,537,0,1 
5388    C   .                                                   Orf1a   5388    A1708D  A   DP=1007 DP4=747,36,1,223    
5648    A   .                                                   Orf1a   5648    K1795Q  C   DP=1014 DP4=10,1000,0,1
```

I would also remove the empty columns `A:L` left in the middle.  I have tried to figure out how to do this using dplyr mutate but I am having trouble getting it all right.  I believe I need to do a string match for `"DP="`, `"DP4="`, and `"IDV="`

How can I get the data collected into the correct columns?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example and please also elaborate a bit more on what exactly you want to do. That‘s not entirely clear to me.

Comment: And please share your data using `dput(YourData)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do to get your values into a "DP", "DP4" and "IDV" columns :

```
x = structure(list(coord = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 3828L, 
5230L, 5388L, 5648L), REF = c("C", "C", "A", "T", "C", "CAA", 
"G", "C", "A"), ALT = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
"."), A = c("DP=1002", "DP=1001", "DP=1006", "DP=793", "DP=793", 
"", "DP=1010", "DP=1007", "DP=1014"), B = c("", "", "", "", "", 
"IDV=2", "", "", ""), C = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
), D = c("", "", "", "", "", "DP=793", "", "", ""), E = c("", 
"", "DP4=549,145,0,0", "", "DP4=331,151,0,0", "", "", "", ""), 
    F = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), G = c("", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), H = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), I = c("DP4=257,729,0,1", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "DP4=444,537,0,1", "", "DP4=10,1000,0,1"), J = c("", "DP4=369,109,178,34", 
    "", "DP4=329,151,2,0", "", "DP4=331,460,0,2", "", "DP4=747,36,1,223", 
    ""), K = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), L = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ORF = c("Orf1a", "Orf1a", 
    "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a", "Orf1a"
    ), Stop = c(1059L, 3267L, 3298L, 3827L, 3828L, 3828L, 5230L, 
    5388L, 5648L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

x = x %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"),
               names_to = "var",
               values_to = "value") %>% #transform to long format
  filter(value != "") %>% #drop empty strings
  mutate(
    type = str_extract(value, ".*(?=\\=)") #extract all values before "="
  ) %>%
  select(-var) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "type", values_from = "value") #pivot to wide format
```